# Obtaining the percentage in sqllite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I made a query with the following statement :

```
select mood, count(*) * 100/ (select count(*) from entry)from entry group by mood having data>data-30 order by mood asc
```

mood is an integer from 0 to 2

the output is :

```
             mood         count       


              0            96,55

              1            3,44
```

is there a way to add a row with mood 2 count 0?

Comment: Remove the mysql tag because the question is explicitly about SQLite.

Comment: Why are you using a `having` clause if you want all the rows?  What is `data`?

Comment: @Asnag Do you have a lookup table where possible values for mood are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT   MOOD, SUM (COUNTER) TOTAL
    FROM   (  SELECT   0 MOOD, 0 COUNTER FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
              SELECT   1 MOOD, 0 COUNTER FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
              SELECT   2 MOOD, 0 COUNTER FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
              SELECT   MOOD,   COUNT ( * )
                             * 100.0
                             / (SELECT   COUNT ( * )
                                  FROM   ENTRY
                                 WHERE   DATA > DATE ('now') - 30)
                FROM   (SELECT   *
                          FROM   ENTRY
                         WHERE   DATA > DATE ('now') - 30)
            GROUP BY   MOOD, DATA)
GROUP BY   MOOD
ORDER BY   MOOD ASC;
```

You have to enumerate (0, 1, 2, .....) all the possible numbers, associating a counter = 0.
Then, you sum the counters grouping by mood.

Please note that your condition having data>data-30 is absurd.
You have to select from ENTRY all the records satisfying the condition data > date('now') - 30, for example.

**SQLite: A VIEW named "dual" that works the same as the Oracle "dual" table can be created as follows: "CREATE VIEW dual AS SELECT 'x' AS dummy;"**

Comment: This was exactly what I want to achieve , I´ve just edit count(*)*100.0 and in Sysdate I substitute for date('now'),great answer :) .

Comment: I've corrected a mistake.  The condition where data > date('now')-30 has to be repeated also in COUNT(*) between parenthesis!!